# Button click not working in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hi all here is my aspx page

```
          <body>
   <% Html.BeginForm("AssignWork", "Project", FormMethod.Post); %>
     <form action="AssignWork.aspx" method="post"></form>
<%:Html.ValidationSummary(true)%>
<div>

<div></div><div style="margin:62px 0 0 203px;"><a style="color:Orange;">Projects : </a><%:Html.DropDownList("Projects")%></div>
<fieldset style="color:Orange;">

    <legend>Employees</legend>
      <% foreach (var item in Model)
         { %>  
              <div>
              <%:Html.CheckBox("EmployeId",new { value=item.EmployeeName})%>
              <%:Html.LabelForModel(item.EmployeeName)%>
              </div>
      <%} %>          
       <p>

</p>       
</fieldset> 
<input type="button" value="Assign" name="Assign" />      
</div>
    <% Html.EndForm(); %>
 </body>
```

And here is my problem that when I click on Assign button its not going to my post method in my control. I am showing this page in a popup window. Can any one tell me where did I do wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Hope you have associated controller & action in place

Answer (score 1):

Try a submit input instead of a button

```
<input type="submit" value="Assign" name="Assign" />
```

Comment: On top of this, you likely want your <form> to enclose all of your field elements, otherwise they will not post when you submit.

Answer (score 0):

change the type of your button to 'submit' :)

Answer (score 0):

You're not using `Html.BeginForm()` correctly. Instead of

```
<% Html.BeginForm("AssignWork", "Project", FormMethod.Post); %>
 <form action="AssignWork.aspx" method="post"></form>
```

try this:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("AssignWork", "Project", FormMethod.Post) { %>
    <!-- your form markup -->
<% } %>
```

You don't need to use a `<form>` tag since its rendered by `Html.BeginForm()`, and `Html.EndForm()` isn't necessary because of the `using` statement - the end tag is rendered at the end of the `using` control block.

And you probably also need to change the input type to `submit`.